# What are the ROS releases like 'indigo' and 'jade' for?

Tags: ros, ros-jade, ros-indigo, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The core packages of these releases look more or less the same. Updates are released for both regularly via the apt repositories. So what is the key point for these named versions? Is is just the list of supported operating systems?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210829/what-are-the-ros-releases-like-%27indigo%27-and-%27jade%27-for?/) by [SR](https://answers.ros.org/users/14071/sr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 152 on 2015-06-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It has to do with API and ABI updates. When a library developer wants to make significant changes to his project, this affects the dependent projects as well. In order to provide a stable interface for users and developers alike, ROS distributions are implemented, so that things are kept somewhat stable between each release!

---

Originally posted by [Progtologist](https://answers.ros.org/users/11081/progtologist/) with karma: 101 on 2015-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While I like @Progtologist's concise answer particularly for the mention of API and ABI, you could also take a look at [Distributions](http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions/new#What_is_a_Distribution.3F) page for the completeness.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-06-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SR](https://answers.ros.org/users/14071/sr/) on 2015-06-17**:
Thank you. That description on the purpose of a distribution is really helpful. "The purpose of the ROS distributions is to let developers work against a relatively stable codebase until they are ready to roll everything forward. "